# Object variable as object property

Tags: vba, object

I have a collection of **Employee** objects in a collection called **MyEmployees**.
I want to assign one of these objects as the superior of the others.
I have created the property **pSuperior** in the class **cEmployee**

Below are the Set and Get methods for the class:

```
Public Property Set Superior(value As Object)
    Set pSuperior = value
End Property

Public Property Get Superior() As Object
    Superior = pSuperior
End Property
```

The Set method gives me no errors at run-time:

```
Set MyEmployees.Item(1).Superior = MyEmployees.Item(2)
```

But when I use

```
Debug.Print MyEmployees.Item(1).Superior.Name
```

to test I get **run-time error 91 object variable or with block not set**

Is my Set Method not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always assign objects to variables (including return values of functions and properties) using `Set`.  So the code for your `Get` method should be:

```
Public Property Get Superior() As Object
    Set Superior = pSuperior
End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're Get property is missing Set for your object assignment as a return value.  I'm not sure what else you may have going on, so here's some sample code of what worked for me (except no collection).  It may also be an improvement to define your Get/Set objects as Employees.

Here's example class code:

```
Private pSuperior As Employee
Private pName As String
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property
Public Property Get Superior() As Employee
    Set Superior = pSuperior
End Property
Public Property Set Superior(Value As Employee)
    Set pSuperior = Value
End Property
```

And Example using the class as you described:

```
Sub test()
    Set John = New Employee
    Set Tim = New Employee
    Set Tim.Superior = John
    John.Name = "John"
    Tim.Name = "Tim"

    MsgBox Tim.Name & "'s Superior is " & Tim.Superior.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, however what worked for me was "...as Object" not "...as Employee". Appreciate the code, though.